# PHP syntax misinterpretation

Tags: php, session, syntax-error

Okay, I'm currently confused as to what the best way to write the code below. I'm confused about how to escape an echo to include more php then carry on the same echo. I sort of understand you need to use double and single " and '. I've included a screenshot of what shows up in chrome when viewing the source as well as the code below.

I managed to get this working on another page, but using the same method it doesn't seem to work on this page.

```
<?php echo "You are logged in as " . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "." ?>
```

Any pointers or direction on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated, even if only in example format.

My image showing what is output - https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKm1D.png

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_name'])){
echo "<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<title>test</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
<div>
'.include 'inc/sidebar.php'; .'
<div id='content-wrapper'>
<div class='page-content'>
'.include 'inc/headerbar.php';.'
'.include 'inc/settings.php';.'
</div><!-- End Page Content -->
</div><!-- End Content Wrapper -->
</div><!-- End Page Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>";
}
else{
echo "You aren't logged in.";
} ?>
```

Comment: Double quotes !== single quotes

Comment: Owh mate, this is very ugly. Who learnt you how to do this?

Comment: @Daan 80% of the tutorials you can find on the Internet, sadly ...

Comment: What do you expect: for single quotes to be accepted as delimiters in a string that is delimited by double quotes? That would be awful

Comment: Both current answers are very good. But PLEASE! PLEASE! one hundred times PLEASE! learn about template engines (for example, I can recommend Smarty, but there are many more)... DO NOT CODE PHP THIS WAY, otherwise, we PHP developers we will always considered "lesser devs" by the community

Comment: @Clément Malet Exactly this, the problem for me is every search I'm bringing up comes up with old techniques or undocumented techniques. If anyone has a place where I can learn the up to date techniques where they're explained that'd be amazing.

Comment: You should try a php framework. Those have good documentation and active community. Just to name a few: Symfony, Laravel, Yii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<title>test</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_name'])): ?>
    <div>
        <?php include 'inc/sidebar.php'; ?>
        <div id='content-wrapper'>
            <div class='page-content'>
                <?php include 'inc/headerbar.php'; ?>
                <?php include 'inc/settings.php'; ?>
            </div><!-- End Page Content -->
        </div><!-- End Content Wrapper -->
    </div><!-- End Page Wrapper -->
<?php else: ?>
    You aren't logged in.
<?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This kind of code remembers me the days when we feared the Y2K bug...

Answer (score 0):

PHP is actually a template engine itself. That's why the `<?php ... ?>` tag set exists in the first place. For big bunches of static HTML, all you need to do is quit PHP mode:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_name'])){ ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
```

Comment: @hidden_4003 Certainly, there're a dozen helper apps that are not that hard (from ORM to CSS preprocessors) but I honestly think that you can learn way more doing things manually (and improving them on each iteration) that just adopting a full-fledged framework from start. It's also the usage example given in the [Your first PHP-enabled page](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php) page of the official manual.